# Timeout configuration for spring webservices with RestTemplate

Tags: java, web-services, spring, timeout, resttemplate

I would like to configure a timeout on the client side for spring webservices using RestTemplate. I tried the following configuration :

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
</constructor-arg>
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
    <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
    <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I have a NoClassDefFoundError when I start my tomcat :

```
06 févr. 2012 10:43:43,113 [ERROR,ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase
```

However I have included commons-httpclient in my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency
```

Any idea of how I could do/fix that?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 9):

Snicolas answer almost worked for me, only had to change the cast Class:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(1000*30);
```

Also you can set the connect timeOut:

```
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(1000*30);
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
( (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) getRestTemplate().getRequestFactory() ).setReadTimeout( 120 * 1000 );
```

I used it in the android version of spring android rest template.

---

Default value is 60 * 1000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and first tried to fix it by modifying the Spring configuration 
but my attempts were all unsucessfull.

Finally, I have partially fixed it by setting the folowing JVM system properties :
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout

sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout

(follow that link for more details about them : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html )

First,  i inject my custom values for "Connect timeout" 
and "Read timeout" stored in a property file, by using an "home made" configuration bean :

```
   <bean id="rmProperties"  class="com.mydomain.myapp.myConfigBean" scope="singleton">
    ...
    <property name="httpRequestConnectTimeout" value="${httpRequestConnectTimeout}" />
    <property name="httpRequestReadTimeout" value="${httpRequestReadTimeout}" />
    ...
    </bean>
```

Then, i set the the JVM system properties by using the System.setProperty(... ) method just like this :

```
    System.setProperty(propName, value);
```

I have only one trouble left : the value set in sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
doesn't seem to be taken in account.
After having made some more tests, i've realized that it happens  when i try to reach my target hosts through a proxy server (Squid in my case).

However ,there is an  inconvenient to use that setting method : the timeout settings will be used for all the further requests

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same needing of being able to set timeout for webservice consumption, and I just solve it with an other spring conf.

First with the configuration bellow, I had the same problem as @jsebFrank (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase)

```
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

But as Spring support explain [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html) (in section 16.5 Timeout Handling), you can use the SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory request factory (which is the default one for Spring restTemplate).

Using it, I don't have problem anymore:

```
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```