# restTemplate.getForObject block thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, block, resttemplate

I use spring boot(1.3.1.RELEASE) to define an interval task(fixedDelay = 500) which call restTemplate.getForObject, but suddenly a few days later the task is no longer scheduled by spring, I use jconsole，I found the method has been waiting for restTemplate.getForObject return for a day, but it don't

who knows the reason?

in the thread stack, you can see 
"
 - locked <0x00000000e272c850> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:244)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:689)
"

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
- locked <0x00000000e272c850> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:244)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:689)
- locked <0x00000000e272c878> (a sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3322)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:180)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.loadMoreGuaranteed(ParserBase.java:459)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishString2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2434)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._finishAndReturnString(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2414)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.getText(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:285)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:514)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.mapObject(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:653)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserialize(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:496)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2810)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
at com.dd.ddfd.clairvoyant.collector.ScheduledSummaryCollector.scheduledCollector(ScheduledSummaryCollector.java:85)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring a read timeout on your rest template? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout) for more details.

Comment: @linqer I have exactly the same issue with the same stack trace you have. Have you found a solution?