# Request timeout in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, timeout

I wish to set my Spring Boot server timeout, say to 15 seconds. To be clear: I wish  that if my server fails to respond within 15 seconds it will return an error response (something like what happens in Heroku, only there it is 30 seconds). **How can I do that?**

My problem actually originates from the fact that this service is a gateway and it calls another service, which sometimes takes a long time to response, and I can't control that service's timeout. Since I'm using an SDK files to call that server, I can't control the outgoing calls. **Is there a way I can globally set a timeout for all outgoing calls?**

Thank you

Comment: Solves http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852236/spring-boot-rest-api-request-timeout your first problem?

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't really work. Application crashes on an exception calling new `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()`. I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout, where on the 3rd answer refers to *Spring Boot* as I need, and now the program runs, but it doesn't stop requests after the given milliseconds. Have I missed some configuration? Any further examples / code / help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your library into a extra thread and then directly join on that thread with timeout.
Example see http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example-with-explanation

Comment: Well, that's a nice trick, but it's a trick. It's not an infrastructural or framework way of doing this. Especially that my service has lots of APIs it introduces, and each such call should be wrapped to run within a thread or such. I thought of that, but I'm looking for something more fundamental.

Comment: @user2339344 Actually, that is a perfectly fundamental solution. It kicks in and does the job cleanly. Maybe add some `ExecutorService` logic for thread pooling or some fancy `CompletableFuture` usage but that's it. Messing with that SDK will most probably bring more problems.