# How to handle timeout for service call

Tags: java, web-services, timeout

I have a struts based application in which I am calling my Restful Web Service. My actual service invocation looks like below:

```
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(testUrl, httpMethod, entity, String.class);
```

Call go through just fine but I want to handle the scenario if in case my service is down I want to timeout in like 1 minute instead of waiting for so long.

Comment: if you use spring RestTemplate, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093036/6743203

Answer (score 1):

You can go for Spring Rest template which provide methods for timeout handling:

For connect timeout:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(2000);
```

For read timeout:

```
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(2000);
```

For more information please visit the documentation page:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html