# Spring “configprops” endpoint can not show ConfigurationProperties options without a getter method

Tags: spring

I'm following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36991745/807695) to add timeout mechanism for resttemplate.

To check whether my config is correct, I go through the output of `configprops` endpoint, the config options about timeout (e.g. `connection-request-timeout`, `connect-timeout`, `read-timeout`) can not be shown in it.

Answer (score 0):

The config options without getter method can not be shown in the return of `configprops` endpoint.

In my case, `connection-request-timeout`, `connect-timeout`, `read-timeout` only have setter methods, so they can be config properly; but they don't have getter methods, it causes they can not be shown in `configprops`