# 504 Gateway timeout Springboot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, timeout

I am working in a Spring boot project and I have a request which is returning a Gateway Timeout 504.
Can I increase this timeout? Is this a property that I can change in the standalone-full.xml?
I am using a wildfly server.

The request is trigger twice in 1 minute, always in 1 mint.

Comment: think this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout

Comment: Occurs the same behavior, look like he ignores the connection time out

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this would help.

```
public HttpClient getBasicAuthDefaultHttpClient() {
    CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, 
    password);
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

    //Fix to avoid HTTP 504 ERROR (GATEWAY TIME OUT ERROR)
    RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
    requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
    requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000);

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
    builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

    return builder.build();
}
```