# Configuring connection and read timeouts for a generated api rest client

Tags: java, spring-boot, timeout, maven-plugin, resttemplate

I am using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to generate an api rest client. I am using the resttemplate library and my pom.xml configuration looks like the following.

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../swagger.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <modelPackage>my.base.package.here</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>my.base.api.package.here</apiPackage>
                            <modelNamePrefix>MyApiPrefix</modelNamePrefix>
                            <configOptions>
                                <library>resttemplate</library>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java</sourceFolder>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

The client generation works sucessfully. Now I am using this client in a spring boot app and I need to configure the connection timeout and the read timeout values.

I was surprised to find no setters for these two properties on the generated ApiClient. So I had to come out with a workaround that uses the RestTemplateBuilder to do that. It looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyApiClientConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public MyApiClientConfiguration(
            final RestTemplate restTemplate,
            final RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder
    ) {
        restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutValue)
                .setReadTimeout(readTimeoutValue)
                .configure(restTemplate);

        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(restTemplate);

        MyApiPrefixApi.setApiClient(apiClient);
    }
}
```

The doc for the `configure` method does not say much:

**configure**

public  T configure(T restTemplate)

> Configure the provided RestTemplate instance using this builder.

Is this the standard approach to configure timeouts when using the resttemplate library? **UPDATE:** My actual implementation does not work (it seems the ResttemplateBuilder own configurations are interfering in a wrong way with the autowired RestTemplate (that I am trying to further configure through the builder)) configuration. The api client generated by other libraries (such as jersey for example) provide a setter to directly configure the timeout using:

```
apiClient.setConnectTimeout(timeoutValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the use of the **configure** method does not work, it is possible to configure the timeout values by creating a RestTemplate bean using the RestTemplateBuilder's **build** method.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(
       RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,
       final int serviceConnectionTimeout,
       final int serviceReadTimeout
        ) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(serviceConnectionTimeout)
            .setReadTimeout(serviceReadTimeout)
            .build();
}
```

Ref: [Spring RestTemplate timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout)