# How to get the connectTimeout value in Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, timeout, resttemplate

I'm learning about RestTemplate in Spring Boot project and I want to log the value of connectTimeout property.

To set this value I can do this implementation:

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf =
        (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
rf.setConnectTimeout(3000);
```

But I want to set it in application.yml like this:

```
  communication:
    http:
      client:
        connectTimeout: '3000'
```

And then, in the configuration class I want to log this value. How can I do this to obtain the value of the connectTimeout in the configuration class? I cannot do `rf.getConnectTimeout();` because this method doesn't exist.
And another question, how Spring set up this connectTimeout value that I added it in the application.yml? Any feedback will be apreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a simple 'set property X' answer.

What I do is create my own `@ConfigurationProperties` class e.g. `RestTemplateProperties` , register it etc.
`RestTemplate` bean and customise my RestTemplate there.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, RestTemplateProperties restTemplateProperties) {
  return restTemplateBuilder
    .setConnectTimeout(restTemplateProperties.getConnectionTimeout())
    .setReadTimeout(restTemplateProperties.getReadTimeout())
    .build();
}
```

Then you *can* set the values in your properties file.

NB: this is isn't *exactly* how I do it, but hopefully you get the idea.