# Unusual 504 Gateway Timeout Issue in Response to Complex Requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Below is the endpoint that receives the request and sends the response. Just before the "return" statement, I am printing out everything but I see the 504 first around 29 seconds later. It is as if the client is waiting for ~29 seconds and decides to throw 504 but the back end prints out the response later on depending on how complex the search is.

I have tried suggestions on [Spring RestTemplate timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout) and added the below code to my main application class. No luck!

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(35000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(35000))
            .build();

}
```

I do not see any issues with the logs, I am using the below ones for logging.

```
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

@PostMapping("/doSomething")
public ResponseEntity<ResultData> getRequest(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) {
    try {
       
        ResultData result = resultService.doSomethingHere(requestData);
        System.out.println("\nresult: " + result.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Is there any other solution out there?
Thanks

Comment: how do you call this WS ? via which tool ?

Comment: The request is sent via the Client. It works well with Postman. I have checked timeout settings on Proxy but nothing appears for 30 seconds.

Comment: if the request works fine with postman, that means you have a proxy or a middle with a 30s timeout

Comment: that is what I thought aswell but there is no indication of any timeout settings for 30 sec on the proxy.

Comment: it could be related that your service is taking too much time, comment this line `resultService.doSomethingHere(requestData);` and retry, see if it's working this time.