# Spring boot call to external api hung with no response

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I've a spring boot java microservice calling one of our external client service outside the k8 cluster. Sometimes, for our requests there are no responses coming back from the external service although it has processed the requests at its end. My logs shows no record after the request went out.

I do have a retry mechanism at my end but since there is no error coming back, it never gets triggered.

Note- i don't have any timeout added to the RestTemplate.

Looking for some ideas/thoughts how to handle this.

Comment: I guess, the request is successfully sent, but no response is given within a default (or implicitly configured) client response timeout. Depending on what particular client is used you can configure it using different properties. For example of you use RestTemplate, it can be configured like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837012/spring-resttemplate-timeout).

Comment: I would check in what state a particular connection has frozen by increasing http client logging level [like this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-logging) and/or using `netstat` and `tcpdump`/`Wireshark` utilities.